# Proving decreasing serie

Tags: sequences-and-series

i need help solving this exercise:
let $(b_{n})$ be a sequence such that $b_{n}$= $[n\left(1-\frac1{\sqrt[n]x}\right)]$ where where $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $n\geq2$, $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $x>1$
Prove that $(b_{n})$ is decreasing :/ Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks like $b_n$ converges.

[image]

octave code:

> function r = bn(n,x) r = n.*(1 - x.^(-1./n)); end
>
> n = [2:50];
>
> y = bn(n,2);
>
> plot(n,y,"o",n,y);
>
> title("bn vs n","fontsize",20) ; grid on

Hint:

$$ b_n = n\left(1 - \frac1{\sqrt[n]x}\right)$$

$$ \sqrt[n]x = \frac1{1 - \frac{b_n}{n}}$$

$$ x = \frac1{\left(1 - \frac{b_n}{n}\right)^n}$$

$x$ is fixed even as $n$ changes.

$$ \frac1{\left(1 - \frac{b_{n+1}}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}} = \frac1{\left(1 - \frac{b_n}{n}\right)^n}$$

$$ 1 - \frac{b_{n+1}}{n+1} = \left(1 - \frac{b_n}{n}\right)^\frac{n}{n+1}$$

$$ \frac{b_{n+1}}{n+1} = 1 - \left(1 - \frac{b_n}{n}\right)^\frac{n}{n+1}$$

Expand the right side and show that $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} b_{n+1} = b_n$ , note that $b_n < n$ when $x > 1$.